# How to set fontfamily in AlertDialog edittext?

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to set fontfamily for alertdialog editext.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Project name");
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            final EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            editText.setHint("Enter your project name");//here how to change text fontfamily
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
            builder.setView(linearLayout);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    final String text = editText.getText().toString();

                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            builder.create().show();
        }
    });
```

I tried with TypeFace but it's not working. if you help me then it would be great and great and i will give you one big upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to these two line and check it working or not.

```
Typeface typeface=Typeface.create("font-family",Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
editText.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
editText.setTypeface(
    Typeface.create("serif", Typeface.NORMAL)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make custom layout file for the dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Project Name"
        android:fontFamily="@fonts/myFont" />
</LinearLayout>
```